# Create a class within a class and instance in outer scope?

Tags: python, class, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to implement consumer - producer problem in Python… The one question I have is whether I can create a class within a class and create an object of it in the outer scope as in the code below:

```
class Main(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        processNumber = 0
        queue_size=5
        self.mutexProducer=thread.allocate_lock()#mutex variablaes
        self.mutexConsumer=thread.allocate_lock()
        self.mutexTeller=thread.allocate_lock()
        self.queue=Queue.Queue(maxsize=queue_size)
        self.producer=Producer(processNumber,random.random())


class Producer(threading.Thread):
    def __int__(self,ProducerID,serviceTime):
        self.id=ProcucerID
        self.serviceTime=serviceTime
    def run(self):
            #mutexProducer.acquire()
            #Entering Critical section
        print queue.qsize()
        if queue.full():
            sleep(random.random())
        else:
            print "Customer %d Enters the Queue" %(self.id)


app=Main()
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Users/sohil/Desktop/sync.py", line 55, in <module>
  app=Main()   File "/Users/sohil/Desktop/sync.py", line 36, in __init__
  self.producer=Producer(processNumber,random.random()) NameError: global name 'Producer' is not defined
```

Comment: Move the `Producer` class _above_ the `Main` class. Since Python is interpreted, and not compiled, when the line of code in `Main` is executed, the interpreter has no idea about the `Producer` class yet. Hence the error. Also, There is a typo, your `__init__` method is named `__int__`

Comment: @karthikr yeah I got that... in Python cant we create some private variables like in c++ where you initialize variable above the constructor?

Comment: No you cannot. The whole point is, interpretation v/s compilation.

Comment: While they won't be private you can create class attributes *outside* of ```__init__```.

Comment: Am I missing something?  In the code above, class Producer is at the same indent level as class Main, it's not nested, and Producer gets defined before Main is used.  In fact I tried a stripped-down version of the code and it works.  Did you forget to indent when typing it in here?  If you do indent Producer within Main, then it becomes an attribute of the Main class, and to refer to it within Main's `__init__` you must say Main.Producer.

Comment: @FutureNerd - There is no point overcomplicating things for a simple usecase such as this - IMO

Answer (score 0):

Change the order.

```
class Producer(threading.Thread):
    def __int__(self,ProducerID,serviceTime):
        self.id=ProcucerID
        self.serviceTime=serviceTime
    def run(self):
            #mutexProducer.acquire()
            #Entering Critical section
        print queue.qsize()
        if queue.full():
            sleep(random.random())
        else:
            print "Customer %d Enters the Queue" %(self.id)

class Main(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        processNumber = 0
        queue_size=5
        self.mutexProducer=thread.allocate_lock()#mutex variablaes
        self.mutexConsumer=thread.allocate_lock()
        self.mutexTeller=thread.allocate_lock()
        self.queue=Queue.Queue(maxsize=queue_size)
        self.producer=Producer(processNumber,random.random())
```

Python is an interpreted language which executes from top to bottom so any dependencies must be declared at the top.

Comment: Can I create classes within classes in python?? So that i can use some global static parameters like the queue?

Comment: @ABC: Just declare those variables at the top level.  There's no need to wrap them in a class.  If you need encapsulation, put them in a separate module.

Comment: @ABC you can create a class within the definition of another class.  You'll find a lot of *don't do that* here at SO but there are a few good posts/answers/examples also.

Comment: Anyway, if you do create a class within a class, the other things in the outer class aren't any easier for the inner class to access than if it were outside--it still has to say OuterClass.thing.  @Kevin is right about using a module.